# How to vertically align items in horizontally ul list with images?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have the following html code:

```html
<div id="footer">
    <ul id="yw1">
        <li><a href="/index.php/site/login">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/index.php/site/login">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="/images/twitter_icon.png" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="/images/facebook_icon.png" /></a></li>
    </ul>       
</div>
```

And the following CSS styles:

```css
#footer {
    margin-top: 25px;
    background: #000000 url(images/background.png) repeat;
    padding: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
#footer ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
}
#footer li {
    padding-left: 20px;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#footer a {
    color:white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Now result is:

[image: screenshot]

But I need to align images and text links by vertically. How can I do it?

Comment: Tried [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align)?

Comment: you can use a table with <tr></tr> for each link. but that's not the best way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As `img` tag is inline by default, it vertically aligns to the baseline and hence you need to use `vertical-align: middle;` for your `img` tag

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7MtKq/178/)

CSS

```css
#footer img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need `vertical-align: middle` on `#footer li` and `#footer a` + `display: inline-block` on images:

```css
#footer li {
    /* ... */
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#footer a {
    /* ... */
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/7kssu/

Answer (score 0):

User following CSS.

```
li { display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change your css

from

```
line-height:normal
```

to

```
line-height:30px
```